# SQLZOO: Derived Table inside the subquery vs Derived Table outside a subquery?

Tags: sql

Question 7 of https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

**"Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area:"**

I'm confused as to why

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world as x
        WHERE x.continent IN (continent))
```

Results in:

```
+-----------+--------+----------+
| continent |   name |    area  |
+-----------+--------+----------+
| Eurasia   | Russia | 17125242 |
+-----------+--------+----------+
```

BUT

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world as x
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world 
        WHERE x.continent IN (continent))
```

OR

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world as x
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world as y
        WHERE x.continent IN (y.continent))
```

Both gives the right result of:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+
|   continent   |    name    |   area   |
+---------------+------------+----------+
| Africa        | Algeria    |  2381741 |
| Oceania       | Australia  |  7692024 |
| South America | Brazil     |  8515767 |
| North America | Canada     |  9984670 |
| Asia          | China      |  9596961 |
| Caribbean     | Cuba       |   109884 |
| Europe        | Kazakhstan |  2724900 |
| Eurasia       | Russia     | 17125242 |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

I don't understand why having a derived table inside the sub-query is different from having a derived table outside a sub-query. Shouldn't they all be the same?

Comment: Btw, there's no *Derived Table* in any of those Selects. You try to write a *Correlated Subquery*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world as x
        WHERE x.continent IN (continent))
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world as x
        WHERE x.continent IN (x.continent))
<=>
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world
  WHERE area >= ALL(SELECT area FROM world as x)
--(assuming that continent is defined as NOT NULL)
-- In result you are searching for biggest country(correct answer - Russia)
```

To avoid that case you should explicitly prefix column names:

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world
  WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area FROM world as x
        WHERE x.continent IN (continent))
=>
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world
WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT x.area FROM world as x
        WHERE x.continent IN (world.continent))
```

Comment: Ohhh, If I understood correctly, without a column prefix, the column will default to the closest table in the scope that has the column name in it.

Comment: @user33428 Yes, the closest scope.

Answer (score 1):

Long comment.. the use of `IN()` there is really terrible and actually infuriating me.  A normal way to write that would be:

```
SELECT continent, name, area 
FROM world x
WHERE area >= ALL
    (SELECT area 
     FROM world y 
     WHERE x.continent = y.continent)
```

It's comparing at a row level (aka 1:1 value compare) so using `IN()` is so misleading, especially considering the source is a tutorial for people learning SQL.

Anyway, see Lukasz's answer for a great answer/explanation of the difference you're seeing.

Comment: Are you saying that I should use    = ANY()     instead of using     IN ()    where ever possible?

Comment: @user33428: `= ANY` the same as `IN` but not easy to understand (most people don't even know it). Aaron meant the `continent IN (continent)`, `IN` is usually used to compare to multiple values.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for the clarification. Also the use of  IN is actually my fault, not from tutorial

Comment: @user33428 Like dnoeth said - it's totally fine to use `IN()` but doesn't make any sense for a single value.  Compare the query `SELECT continent FROM world WHERE country = 'US'` vs. `SELECT continent FROM world WHERE country IN('US')`.  Both will work, the latter is just needlessly complicated, and in your specific example, it makes it seem like the `IN()` may be important but it's not.

Comment: Whoops. My misunderstanding of correlated subqueries made me think x.continent was a list of values within the scope of the subquery instead of it being one value.

Comment: @user33428 It's SQLZOO's fault, their sample query does that

Answer (score 0):

The different behaviour is because in the first example, there is no join on `Continent` between the outer and inner queries.

In the 2nd and 3rd queries, `x` is an alias of the `world` table in the outer query, and specifiying `x.Continent IN (continent)` in the inner query restricts the rows returned by the inner query to those that match the Continent value on each row in the outer query.

In the first query, you are simply aliasing the `world` table in the inner table, and there is no link between the Continent values in the inner and outer query, so the >= operator is effectively being applied to all records in the `World` table, meaning you only get the row with the largest value returned.